# What is the 'correct' way to identify the currently active application in OSX 10.6+?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to identify which OSX application is currently active.  I understand that in OSX 10.5, this could be done with:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] activeApplication]
```

however, this has been deprecated in 10.6+.

The apple developers documentation states that this should be done through the 'active' property of the NSRunningApplication object.  I thought one way to approach this might be to get the list of all running applications through

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]
```

and then loop through, checking the 'active' property of each application.  However, the following test code doesn't behave as I expected: when compiled and run from Terminal.app, only the "terminal" app is ever marked as active, regardless of whether I select a different application.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSRunningApplication.h>
#import <AppKit/NSWorkspace.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  while(1){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *currApp;
    NSArray *runningApps;
    runningApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
    for (id currApp in runningApps) {
      if ([currApp isActive])
          NSLog(@"* %@", [currApp localizedName]);
      else
          NSLog(@"  %@", [currApp localizedName]);
    }
    sleep(1);
    [pool release];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Have I misunderstood how the "active" property works?

(Also, please feel free to criticise my Objective C code --- this is my first attempt at objective C, so I know it's likely to be hideously ugly to the trained eye!  Please forgive me! :)  Any suggestions welcome.)

Comment: Hi Josh --- no; I'm actually coding on 10.6, and ownsMenuBar is 10.7.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use `NSRunningApplication.current`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is that your application is unable to receive any events from the system informing it that the current application has changed, and therefore it never updates the active property on the `NSRunningApplication` instances. If I use the exact same code, but another app is active when I start running the code, it reports that application instead.

If instead you change your code to run the main thread's `NSRunLoop` and use a 1-second timer, it should work.

Here's a quick example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject
- (void)run;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)run {
    for (NSRunningApplication *currApp in [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]) {
        if ([currApp isActive]) {
            NSLog(@"* %@", [currApp localizedName]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"  %@", [currApp localizedName]);
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"---");
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    Foo *foo = [[Foo new] autorelease];
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                      target:foo
                                                    selector:@selector(run)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];

    [p release];
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin,  Thanks very much for your response.  Could you point me in the direction of any documentation about how to enable my app to receive such events?  Thanks!

Comment: @duncanm: The important point is you need to be running the main `NSRunLoop`, and you need to let control return to the run loop. I just updated my answer with an example that does exactly this. It uses an `NSTimer` to invoke the method ever second, and the method itself only iterates over the applications once and returns. This way control is returned to the runloop so it can receive events, and 1 second later it calls the method again.

Comment: Ahh.  Brilliant.  I was thinking of using an NSTimer originally, and then got lazy and used a while loop!  I guess wouldn't have had a problem if I'd gone that way to start with.  Thanks!

Comment: This post is about 4 years old, but NSWorkspace management is still the same. Just a heads up: for the love of god, you do NOT need to loop to find the active application. Use  `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] menuBarOwningApplication]` or `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication]`. If you want to be notified of changes, you don't need to poll; subscribe to `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`.

Answer (score 21):

Polling every second or so to find out the current application is inefficient, and is the wrong way to go about this. A much better approach it to simply set your process up to receive the [`NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW97) notification.

```
@interface MDAppController : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSRunningApplication    *currentApp;
}
@property (retain) NSRunningApplication *currentApp;
@end

@implementation MDAppController 
@synthesize currentApp;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                      selector:@selector(activeAppDidChange:)
               name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)activeAppDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.currentApp = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
    NSLog(@"currentApp == %@", currentApp);
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    MDAppController *appController = [[MDAppController alloc] init];
    [NSApp setDelegate:appController];
    [NSApp run];
    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `currentApplication` returns the `NSRunningApplication` that represents the application running the code, not the application that's foremost in the UI.

Comment: Hi NSGod - I did try that, but it also didn't seem to work (perhaps for the same reason that Kevin suggests below --- i.e. that my application can't receive events?) --- in fact, if I print out "[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] localizedName]" I get "null", not "Terminal.app", and this does not change when I activate a different application)

Comment: @NSGod: Repeated calls to `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is a rather silly way of implementing a timer.

Comment: @KevinBallard: And using a timer to repeatedly poll for the active app is a silly way to keep track of the active app.

Comment: @NSGod: I agree, but I got the impression the OP wasn't trying to track changes to the active app, but rather just trying to figure out how to *get* the active app. His loop was just an attempt to see the active status change, to ensure it works. At least, that's how I interpreted it.

Comment: Works fine. Good example using events.

Answer (score 13):

As of OS X 10.7 `NSWorkspace` also has the convenient method:

```
- (NSRunningApplication *)frontmostApplication;
```

Also you could now use Grand Central dispatch calls to make repetitive calls with timeout.

Something like this:

```
- (void) checkFrontmostApp {

    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSRunningApplication* runningApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];
        //do something
        NSLog(@"frontmost app: %@", runningApp.bundleIdentifier);
        [self checkFrontmostApp]; //'recursive' call
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Clean, simple, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The notes for NSWorkspace's [`activeApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/activeApplication) say:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> It is strongly suggested that you use the NSRunningApplication
>   classes’
>   [`currentApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSRunningApplication/currentApplication)
>   or activemethods to retrieve this information in applications targeted
>   for Mac OS X v10.6 and later.

You should probably do a 10.6 & newer set of code and a 10.5.X and older set of code there.

B.T.W., the NSWorkspace method was only marked deprecated as of 10.7, but NSRunningApplication came in as of 10.6.

Oh, here's an alternative that is 64-bit compatible if you include the Application Services framework:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    CFShow(CFSTR("Hello, World!\n"));
    ProcessSerialNumber psn;

    OSErr err = GetFrontProcess(&psn);
    if(err == noErr)
    {
        ProcessInfoRec info;
        StringPtr processName = malloc(64);

        if(processName)
        {
            bzero(processName, 64);
            info.processInfoLength = sizeof(ProcessInfoRec);
            info.processName = processName;
            err = GetProcessInformation( &psn, &info);
            if(err == noErr)
            {
                fprintf(stdout, "front most process name is %s", processName+1 );
            }
            free(processName);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response.  I did try using "currentApplication", but that returns the application from which the call was made (i.e. in my case, I get "null" for the localizedName, because I'm running a command line process).  I'd like to avoid using activeApplication for exactly the reason you suggest --- i.e. that it's been deprecated.  However, using "active" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSNotificationCenter *allApplicationsNotificationCenter;

    allApplicationsNotificationCenter = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter];

    [allApplicationsNotificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationActivated:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)applicationActivated:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] menuBarOwningApplication] localizedName]);

}
```