# what is the way to identify active application in OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I could find the solution here [What is the 'correct' way to identify the currently active application in OSX 10.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348627/what-is-the-correct-way-to-identify-the-currently-active-application-in-osx-10). 
But the solutions provided are using infinite loop. I want the flow to return back to main say after 15 secs. I am very new to objective-c, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at the answer which suggests `didActivateApplicationNotification`. This is **not**  using infinite loop aka polling.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @vadian. I used the answer suggested by you had to make a small change in it to return back to the calling method. I have added my own event loop and removed [NSApp setDelegate:appController]; and [NSApp run];