# How to have an event-loop on non-main thread in macOS?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, events, nsworkspace

Related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896395/how-to-get-if-a-window-has-focus-on-macos): I have the need to gather information about what is the current active application, on macOS.

The linked QA answer provide a mechanism to get alerted (event) when the active application changes, but it crashes when run on a separated thread:

```
FocusDetector::AppFocus focus;
focus.run();

//std::thread threadListener(&FocusDetector::AppFocus::run, &focus); //Does not works
//if (threadListener.joinable())
//{
//  threadListener.join();
//}
```

.

```
    *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /xxxxxxx/NSUndoManager.m:363
2020-11-24 08:54:41.758 focus_detection[81935:18248374] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation            0x00007fff3006cb57 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib           0x00007fff68eb35bf objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation            0x00007fff30095d08 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                0x00007fff32787e9d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   Foundation                0x00007fff326c45ee +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 440
    5   AppKit                    0x00007fff2d25165c -[NSApplication run] + 864
    6   focus_detection           0x0000000104b1a010 _ZN13FocusDetector8AppFocus3runEv + 128
    7   focus_detection           0x0000000104b19547 _ZNSt3__1L8__invokeIMN13FocusDetector8AppFocusEFvvEPS2_JEvEEDTcldsdeclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT0_Efp0_Efp_spclsr3std3__1E7forwardIT1_Efp1_EEEOT_OS6_DpOS7_ + 119
    8   focus_detection           0x0000000104b1944e _ZNSt3__1L16__thread_executeINS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS2_EEEEMN13FocusDetector8AppFocusEFvvEJPS7_EJLm2EEEEvRNS_5tupleIJT_T0_DpT1_EEENS_15__tuple_indicesIJXspT2_EEEE + 62
    9   focus_detection           0x0000000104b18c66 _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEMN13FocusDetector8AppFocusEFvvEPS8_EEEEEPvSD_ + 118
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00007fff6a260109 _pthread_start + 148
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib   0x00007fff6a25bb8b thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

This is obviously related with `NSApplication`, for which the documentation state:

> Every app uses a single instance of NSApplication to control the main event loop

In consequence, I am looking for another way to listen on events, which is not restricted to the main event-loop ( or main thread.

Intuitively, it should be possible to get information about the current application with focus, in a separated thread.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, sorry for not providing much research. I did researched on internet for "NSNotification not in main thread" and other similar sentences, but without success.

### Question:

How to listen on `activeAppDidChange` NSNotification outside the main thread?

Comment: well, wrapping use of notification observer in a c++ class does not change the thread they are posted on.

Comment: Correct, but as soon as I un-comment the lines creating a thread and calling AppFocus::run inside, it crash with "is only safe to invoke on the main thread", so I guess it's related to running NSApplication::run inside a thread.

Comment: `+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.` That is a problem far from NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification. What are you trying to do, what is your goal ? And in a different thread asking for another apps state needs to take care that the other apps main thread disappears.

Comment: What is my goal?: a background application, which needs to detect which application (PID) has focus. The main thread is not available (this would imply far too much refactoring, probably hundreds thousands lines). I can create a listener thread, but it will not be the main thread. The linked answer is a full example, the lines creating the thread are commented so far.

Comment: You know that my example did just that..`pid_t pid = ((NSRunningApplication *)note.userInfo[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey]).processIdentifier;`, the example with a separate thread and a thread manager also.

Comment: Possibly, I am still trying to make it to work in my environment, that is why I did not answered yet. (I am really noob with objective-c, I usually work with C++)

Comment: lts chat if you like

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225017/discussion-between-adrian-maire-and-ol-sen).

Answer (score 0):

Place Observers to the following Notifications below and let them invoke your methods. NotificationCenter are *singleton* for good reason, while you can of course, create your own. `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]` is a singleton i guess, and `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` as named - the notification center to observe. The sending object to expect is `nil` in your case, because you don't know which object to observe more specific.

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
```

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(activeAppDidChange:)
        name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
        object:nil
    ];
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(activeAppDidTerminate:)
        name:NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification
        object:nil
    ];
    // id<NSObject> myObserver;
    _myObserver = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] 
        addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceDidHideApplicationNotification
        object:nil 
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
        usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
            // do stuff in block
            NSRunningApplication *app = note.userInfo[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
            NSLog(@"%u %@ %ld", 
               app.processIdentifier, 
               app.bundleIdentifier, 
               (long)app.activationPolicy
            );
        }
    ];
}
-(void)activeAppDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"%@",note.userInfo.debugDescription);
}
-(void)activeAppDidTerminate:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"%@",note.userInfo.debugDescription);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand the meaning of it: 1) "Place observers to ..." This seems to add new event listeners.
2) I am also not sure why Singleton and main-thread are related. 
3) Finally, I don't get at all the comment about "nil".

Comment: On my IDE, cmd+click will follow a token, to it declaration.

Comment: To be more clear, if this answer is just suggesting to create a event loop in the main thread, I just can't.

Comment: NotificationCenter's are thread safe and you can add an observer in the thread you want. Just tested again to be very sure. Works with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]` as well. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

Comment: i make another answer, to show you proof of concept. You will tell me if that is an extra event on mainThread or not.. deal?

Answer (score 0):

Just proof you can receive Notifications on Threads that are not mainThread.

```
// ThreadManagerExample.h
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ThreadManagerExample : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL started;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) uint64_t looptime;
-(void)start;
-(void)stop;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

```
// ThreadManagerExample.m
#import "ThreadManagerExample.h"

static const double kThreadPriority = 1.0;

@interface ReceivingThread : NSThread
@property (nonatomic, weak) ThreadManagerExample * threadManager;
@end

@interface ThreadManagerExample ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) ReceivingThread *thread;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL started;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) uint64_t looptime;
@end

@implementation ThreadManagerExample
-(void)dealloc {
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startThread) object:nil];
    if ( _thread ) {
        [_thread cancel];
        while ( !_thread.isFinished ) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
        }
    }
}
-(instancetype)init {
    if ( !(self = [super init]) ) return nil;
    _looptime = 1000000000; // 1 sec
    return self;
}

-(void)startThread {
    if ( !_thread) {
        self.thread = [ReceivingThread new];
        _thread.threadManager = self;
        _thread.name=@"ReceivingThread";
        [_thread setThreadPriority:kThreadPriority];
        [_thread start];
    }
}

-(void)start {
    if ( !_thread ) {
        @synchronized ( self ) {
            self.started = YES;
        }
        [self performSelector:@selector(startThread) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}

-(void)stop {
    @synchronized ( self ) {
        self.started = NO;
    }
    if ( _thread ) {
        [_thread cancel];
        self.thread = nil;
    }
}
@end

@implementation ReceivingThread {
    BOOL somethinghappend;
    NSString *oldBundleIdentifier;
    NSString *lastbundleIdentifier;
    pid_t oldPID;
    pid_t focusedPID;
}
-(instancetype)init {
    if (!(self=[super init])) return nil;
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mimi:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
    return self;
}
-(void)mimi:(NSNotification*)note {
    NSRunningApplication *app = note.userInfo[NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
    lastbundleIdentifier = app.bundleIdentifier;
    focusedPID = app.processIdentifier;
    if (![oldBundleIdentifier isEqualToString:lastbundleIdentifier]) {
        somethinghappend = YES;
    }
    oldBundleIdentifier = lastbundleIdentifier;
    oldPID = focusedPID;
}
-(void)main {
    [NSThread setThreadPriority:kThreadPriority];
    while ( !self.isCancelled ) {
        uint64_t nextLoop = 0;
        @synchronized ( _threadManager ) {
            if (somethinghappend) {
                NSLog(@"%@ %u",lastbundleIdentifier, focusedPID);
                somethinghappend = NO;
            }
            uint64_t now = mach_absolute_time();
            nextLoop = now + _threadManager.looptime;
        }
        mach_wait_until(nextLoop);
    }
}
@end
```

and instance and starting is done like..

```
if (!_manager) _manager = [[ThreadManagerExample alloc] init];
[_manager start];
```

stopping

```
[_manager stop];
_manager = nil; // if needed
```

So as looptime is set to 1 sec it will check each second if the last received bundleIdentifier was changed. You could extend the `-(void)mimi:` method by checking if the bundleIdentifier differs from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` to know if you became active yourself and ignore that when needed.

**Edit** from [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication?language=objc)

> `NSRunningApplication` is thread safe, in that its properties are returned atomically. However, it is still subject to the main run loop policy described above. If you access an instance of NSRunningApplication from a background thread, be aware that its time-varying properties may change from under you as the main run loop runs (or not).

Comment: To test this code, I created an empty console project in objective-c. I copied both files in the project, and added a main.m with main() function. The main function alloc/init/start a ThreadManagerExample, wait 10s and release everything. I can see ::start() is called, but otherwise, the program does nothing.

Comment: console projects don't run permanent unless you make them to do so. Better try it with an NSApplication from the templates and place `#import "ThreadManagerExample.h"` in the header of `ViewController.h` and the alloc/init & start in `-(void)ViewDidLoad`. And then watch your console.log in xcode..

Comment: That is why I sleep 10s.